# Wordpress: How can I hook only on certain pages? Can I even do that?

Tags: wordpress

So I created a action `add_action( 'header',    'admin_bar', 8 );`, so that it loads in the header. However, I don't want it to load on certain pages, for example, `post-new.php`. Can I have a condition for hooks to load only certain pages?

Comment: Try this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_head-on-certain-admin-pages-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a $pagenow global.  not sure if it's still there but you could var_dump($pagenow) on the pages you want to exclude to find the value then do something like this in your function...

```
function admin_bar() {
  global $pagenow;
  if ( 'post-new' != $pagenow || 'dashboard' != $pagenow ) {
   //execute code
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a variable for just the backend? Like, if(in backend) then x.

Because the dashboard one isn't working. Also, you have to use post-new.php instead of just post-new.

Comment: Actually, there is a better way than using $pagenow. You can use is_admin()

Comment: @Strawberry, `is_admin` is a boolean; how would it let you determine if it is the specific page you want and not just some other admin page? Besides, it returns `1` for `post-new.php` which is exactly what you said you didn’t want.